# DirectXTex Resize returns an empty ScratchImage

Tags: directx

I have this code

```
DirectX::ScratchImage DSResizedImage;
        
DirectX::Resize(*tex->DSImage.GetImage(0,0,0), tex->scaleX, tex->scaleY,
    DirectX::TEX_FILTER_FLAGS::TEX_FILTER_DEFAULT, DSResizedImage);
        
DirectX::Image Resized1 = *DSResizedImage.GetImage(0, 0, 0);
```

which returns an empty Image.

However, it does work when using what should be the equivalent with OpenCV

```
std::string save = fullSavePath + tex->hash + ".PNG";
tex->tex2Other(fullSavePath + tex->hash + ".dds", "png");

cv::Mat cvIm = cv::imread(save, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
if (cvIm.empty())
{
    printf("Tex not written!");
    exit(1);
}
cvIm.copyTo(res(cv::Rect(tex->offsetX, tex->offsetY, tex->scaleX, tex->scaleY)));
```

The problem with using the OpenCV solution is that sometimes users will get this error when resizing (which I can't get to replicate on my computer in debug):
`OpenCV(4.5.3) Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in cv::Mat::Mat, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 811`

For this specific image, it's dimensions (and scaleX/scaleY) are 2048x1024.
Any help would be very appreciated! :)

Comment: What was the ``HRESULT`` that came back from ``Resize`` with DirectXTex?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to check. It returned `E_NOINTERFACE`

Comment: Did you initialize COM? See [the wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/DirectXTex).

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved it! I must have forgotten to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DirectXTex function **Resize** was returning a failed HRESULT: `E_NOINTERFACE`. This happens when you use DirectXTex methods that use the Windows Imaging Component (WIC) without initializing COM on the calling thread.

> Note that for Windows Runtime applications (such as UWP and/or C++/WinRT), COM is initialized as part of the Windows Runtime initialization.

This issue is documented on the [DirectXTex wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/DirectXTex).